# Frost blur header

Tags: css, background, blur, css-filters

Here is the Overwatch subreddit link
https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/.

[image: screenshot]

There is a header with a stained/frost glass effect like in the image above. I tried to get how it's done. I know it uses 2 images: a crisp and a blurred one. It seems the whole thing works with CSS alone and I'd like to reproduce the effect. Any hints on how to do it?

Comment: Does my answer help? If it does, please accept. If not, feedback please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to create a second rectangular element on top of the image with a CSS blur filter:

```
filter: blur(20px);
```

---

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg);
    background-position: left bottom;
}

#gloss {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

#gloss::before {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg);
    background-position: left bottom;
    -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
    content: ' ';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="gloss"></div>
</div>
```

This creates this gloss effect on the lower half:

[image: application]

See a working example [on JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/dw5ywnm2/2/).

You can see [CSSTricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/frosting-glass-css-filters/) for a great explanation on this.

Comment: setting the background position to left bottom won't work if you scroll the page, the background picture is fixed while the overlay pucture moves on scroll, so ty overlay with blur needs to move on scroll

Answer (score 0):

Its actually quite simple, just have two div over each other. Parts that matter are the `background-position` and `top` / `bottom` positions.

```css
.imgWrapper{
 position: relative;
 width:500px;
 height:91px;
}
.overlayImages{
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
}
.topImg{
 top: 0;
 background-image: url("//b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/0HMyksNbyvcoEx2-35Gf151KTV_QzKa6ihNNYedlqLo.jpg");
 background-position: left top;
}

.bottomImg{
 height: 50%;
 bottom: 0;
 background-image: url("//b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/kDrC4XsFDhy6yP82_DAoDVNa0DXWgwlFGVeuED8TrNo.jpg");
 background-position: left bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgWrapper">
 <div  class="overlayImages topImg"></div>
 <div  class="overlayImages bottomImg"></div>
</div>
```

container

Comment: I know how you can make it as a static either with blur and the original or a double file mechanism (both anchored to bottom) but I'd like to know how to get it to work with scroll, sorry should've stated my intent clearer :)